# How to get rid of mintsystem and other mint components

Tags: 14.04, apt, mint

I installed some parts of linuxmint rosa in Ubuntu 14.04.5 by adding the repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. For example, if I switch to `tty2`, it shows up as Linux Mint 17 Rosa. I would like everything to resemble a Ubuntu 14.04 installation as closely as possible. How do I remove these mint components?

Comment: Which repository(-ies) have you added and exactly which package(s) did you install?

Comment: You mention tty2 which implies to me its a text message you see. I'd `grep` looking for the text-string you see to get a filename, then look for the package that contains that file (eg. `dpkg -S`) though you could probably just edit the file directly...  (yes I'd probably re-install the Ubuntu versions too)

Comment: @pomsky http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa

Comment: @guiverc that was just a random example that I was giving. Everything except lsb_release seems to identify my system as Linux Mint

Comment: Rule #1 of Linux/Ubuntu: **Do not mix and match repositories for different OSes even if the repositories are compatible with each other.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Synaptic Package Manager.

1. Install Synaptic

   ```
   sudo apt-get install synaptic
   ```
2. Open it with

   ```
   synaptic-pkexec
   ```
3. On the left window side select *Origin*.
4. Scroll this list to something `linuxmint` related. Then it will show  packages in the right (installed ones should have green square mark).
5. You can remove or purge them with corresponding menu entries.
6. Do not forget to click *Apply* when you are done.

---

Or `aptitude`:

```
aptitude search "?origin (linuxmint) ?installed"
```

Then remove or purge found packages by hand.

Comment: Yep. This did a large part of the work. Additionally, I had to install the base-files package as a .deb package and then upgrade it to report the correct distro and version